# office web word Addin

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, office365, office-js

What is the best method to get SharePoint list items from Office Web Addin using the credentials of the logon user?

We have migrated to Office 365, I am not sure whether i must authenticate on AD or Office 365, the Office Addin App will be deployed on SharePoint on Premise

I have tried rest services but I am not sure of how to pass the user token, for authentication.

```
function GetSharePointListItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "weburl/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/Items?$select=Title,ParagraphText&$filter=ParagraphText isnotnull ",
        type: "GET",
        Authorization: {"Bearer " + accessToken},
         headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d.results) {
                   OnSuccessSharePointData();
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
            OnErrorSharePointData();

        }
    });
```

any ideas

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean when you say you have tried rest services? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Hi there I am getting an access denied error using rest services,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your add-in ***does*** have to get authorization to SharePoint Online/Office 365. Asking "what's the best way" is pretty broad, so here are some starting points about auth to SP/O365:

- [Understanding and Using the SharePoint 2013 REST Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198245.aspx)
- [Authorize external services in your Office Add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/auth-external-add-ins)

(When you say that you will deploy the add-in on SharePoint on Premise, I assume that you mean that you will deploy the add-in manifest in a SharePoint corp catalog. Is that right?)